# iPhone - Write a delegate and overload methods

Tags: xml, parsing, delegates, overloading

i would like to know how can i write a class delegate and overload its method.
An example : i would like to write a class ( a class that i'll set as delegate of an object ) that have to be the new delegate of an NSXMLParser object. And i would want to write a method that overload the didStartElement and foundCharacters methods. How can i do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a delegate of an object you have to use @protocol .
To overload method you have to subclass the object you want to overload.